# How Do I Convert This Function Based View To An UpdateView?

Tags: django

I am trying to convert a function based view to a class based view. I've done it with the CreateView but the UpdateView is giving me grief. It won't take my update. I can get the view to take my update, but it doesn't save it.

Here's my function based view:

```
def update_task_update_view(request, pk):

    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = TaskForm(request.POST or None, instance=task)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("MyTasks:task_detail", pk=task.id)

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "task": task
    }

    return render(request, "partials/task_form.html", context)
```

And here was my attempt at a Class Based View.

```
class UpdateTaskUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Task
    form_class = TaskForm
    template_name = 'partials/task_form.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
 
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.save()
            task.save()
            return redirect("MyTasks:task_detail", pk=task.id)
        else:
            return render(request, "partials/task_form.html", {
                "form":form
            })
```

This function based view is working fine, no issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an assist from FB...Travis Tucker....

I did this instead and it seems to be working fine...

```
class UpdateTaskUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Task
    form_class = TaskForm
    template_name = 'partials/task_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.save()
            task.save()
            return redirect("MyTasks:task_detail", pk=task.id)
        else:
            return render(request, "partials/task_form.html", {
                "form":form
            })
```